# Complete change of hardware

Tags: drivers, 20.04, hardware

Will my current Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS work on a completely new system (new hardware) if i simply plug in my old HDD into the new system?

As far as I know, the drivers are in the kernel which is what makes the OS most stable and hence there is no need for installation of drivers. The OS usually works fine on any system/hardware that is around a year old.

Comment: The answer is, as always, "it depends". Reinstalling is, as always, a much better option.

Comment: I had a USB full installation of Xubuntu 20.04 which worked flawlessly with three computers (one desktop made in 2008, a laptop from 2013 and a laptop from 2017) without any dedicated graphics card. In case you don't have a dedicated graphics card, it would most likely work. In case there are issues, you can always reinstall :)

Comment: It could work but best practice is to reinstall the OS with new hardware. Also consider the fact that everything might appear to work just fine without a reinstall but some software is actually optimised with your old hardware and that optimization ends up causing worse performance on the new hardware. Presumably you obtained new hardware because it's better, why *wouldn't* you reinstall and make sure that everything is optimized for your current hardware, and not slowed down by software that still has configs for the old.

Comment: Thanks a lot for removing my doubts!!!

Answer (score 2):

It might / it can.

I recently moved a hard drive with a 18.04 Ubuntu MATE installation from an old HP laptop to an even older Dell laptop.

It worked seamlessly, but these were simple machines without dedicated graphics cards, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! My doubts are gone.

Answer (score 1):

with some preparations it can work. (I made it for some years).

I would search which closed sources driver or firmware  you need on your new hardware and install it on your old hardware.

then I would to remove closed source drivers  (like nvidia or for wlan cards) which was needed on your old system but not on your new hardware.

and a backup is not a bad Idea; also to have a bootable usb-stick/DVD

sorry I'm not good in explaning in english.